# Help with javascript SDK configuration

Tags: support, api, javascript, api-v2.2, oauth2

The following problem is **REAL**! All names have been changed to protect the *innocent*.

I have a site at "http://Something.github.io/MyRepository/Directory/index.html"

And I have my app configured like so:

- Client Id: 1234
- Key: -ABC123((
- OAuth Domain: "Someting.github.io"
- Application Website: "http://Something.github.io/MyRepository/Directory"
- Client Side Flow Is Enabled

And the API is configured like so:

```
SE.init({
   clientId: 1234,
   key: '-ABC123((',
   channelUrl: 'http://Something.github.io/MyRepository/Directory/proxy.html',
   complete: function() { }
});
```

And then I call the authenticate function like so:

```
SE.authenticate({
   networkUsers: true,
   scope: [],
   success: MySuccessResponder,
   error: MyErrorResponder
});
```

I get a child window with the following address:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstackexchange.com%2Foauth%2Flogin_success%3Fassisted%3D4573%26protocol%3Dhttp%26proxy%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252FSomething.github.io%252FMyRepository%252FDirectory%252Fproxy.html&client_id=1234&state=4
```

Which shows me an "approve" and "reject" button.
When I click "approve" I get this error:

```
"error description: Cannot return to provided redirect_uri"
```

Apparently I am the only person having this problem or my searching skills are sucking.

I have already tried setting the OAUTH Domain to the following:

- github
- github.io
- github.com
- Something.github
- PleaseDieInAFire.com

So I'm sure I'm missing something. Plz 2 halp!

Comment: Related or duplicate: http://stackapps.com/questions/6678/getting-application-not-configured-for-implicit-grants-error-trying-to-setup-w

Answer (score 3):

Of course as soon as I finally break down and ask a question I see my mistake:

```
Applications that have the client side flow enabled can use https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success as their redirect_uri by default.
```

I had "Desktop OAuth Redirect Uri" disabled which the javascript SDK uses. (Note the url posted in the question)

Leaving this up here in case anyone else is as foolish as I.