# iOS Client for stackoverflow always throws redirect_uri not a valid uri

Tags: support, api-v2.2, authentication, oauth2

I tried to use the Stack Exchange API to authenticate the user.

I have registered my app with `redirect_uri` as `stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`.

But it always throws "redirect_uri is not a valid uri".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means either that you've misconfigured the app or that the authentication call is incorrect.

Note that `stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success` is not a valid `redirect_uri` irregardless.

You probably want/need to use **Client side** (Implicit) authentication, in which case the `redirect_uri` would be:

`https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`

Note the **mandatory** `https://`.

Be sure your app is configured as shown in [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6679/7653).

Then you can use a URL like the following to authenticate:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id={YOUR CLIENT ID}&scope=no_expiry&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success
```

When you fetch that page, something like this will end up as the redirected-to URL:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=wdR8Lm7m4ibD48lfrCcFxQ))&expires=86399
```

You would then use the `access_token` to make an API query like:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/30028657/answers?site=stackoverflow&key=RoZwtHUrhMP088oVGCMlxA((&access_token=wdR8Lm7m4ibD48lfrCcFxQ))&filter=!)4k-FmUi-xgG3sdSdPz*cQNNqR0A
```

(Note that the example token, above, has long since been invalidated.  Use your own values for it and for `key`.)

Comment: I am unable to give https:// in oauth domain field , it throws error saying port is not allowed in oauth domain

Comment: Use the setting as shown in [this answer](http://stackapps.com/a/6679/7653) **EXACTLY** (Except for name and description).

Comment: I should give stackexchange.com in app registeration and should give "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success" while making the call.

Comment: Correct at last. :)

Comment: I have done all this steps and now i want to authenticate using Stack Exchange API using login form. Can some one tell the steps how to do it?@BrockAdams