# Getting an API key for an application without a server

Tags: support, api, api-key, oauth2

When I go to register my application, it asks me my OAUTH application URL. But I don't have an OAuth server and I just want to get the api-key without my server.

How can I fill out the form required to get api-key that will be used by my android client application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a server to get an API key, or even to use OAuth2.

Set ***OAuth Domain*** to: `stackexchange.com`, and
***Application Website*** to: `https://stackapps.com/`.

See [this other answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6679/7653) for more information.

Comment: It works! Then can I send requests to api.stackexchange.com with jsoup or other HTTP libraries?

Comment: You can send queries even without a key, and using any tool that can fetch URL's and parse the JSON response. ... Look up how to do this; jsoup doesn't seem like a productive approach for API use.